# How to use pagespeed_optimize_image.exe for bulk image optimization?

Tags: image, pagespeed

For one image this can be done by

```
pagespeed_optimize_image.exe image.jpg image_optimised.jpg
```

in cmd line.
But is it possible to use this tool for bulk image optimization?

Answer (score 0):

Pop open your powershell and run the following:

Warning: This will replace all your jpg files as the output is the same as the input.

Warning: This will only work on jpg files as you can see the filter below, change to use pngs too.

`Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg | ForEach { D:\absolute\path\to\pagespeed_optimize_image.exe $_.Fullname $_.Fullname }`